# how can i disable the attachedCallback and detachedCallback

Tags: aframe

I try to change the scene hierarchy. The appendChild method work but the attachedCallback and detachedCallback are called too. I want just perform the appendChild's native code only.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really for A-Frame's custom elements. The callbacks are critical. Maybe you can monkeypatch or inherit the prototypes (e.g., AFRAME.AEntity.prototype)? But heavily, heavily not recommended and strange.

Comment: All I'm trying to do is change the parent, but appendChildCallback removes the element and regenerates it. ince all components are also deleted, I must copy all components, including object3D, which is very inefficient. Moreover, if i'm trying to move a sub-tree rather than an element, the duplicate overhead becomes very burdensome.
So I want to disable callback temporarily and enable it again.

Comment: Okay, the original question did not mention this. This was recently addressed at https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/pull/4121

Comment: Thank you. It's that i need. By the way the url "https://aframe.io/releases/0.9.1/aframe.min.js" response 404 status. can you confirm that?